# /bin/sh -c "read var; echo $var" not using value read

Tags: bash, input

I am trying to store the username provided by user in a variable and then use that username to login to a server via ssh.

This seems to work

```
amit@sharknado:~$ read -p "username: " username; ssh -l $username localhost
username: foobartest
foobartest@localhost's password:
```

However, when i do the same with `/bin/sh -c`, `$username` doesnt seem to be stored?

```
amit@sharknado:~$ /bin/sh -c "read -p \"username: \" username; ssh -l $username localhost"
username: foobar
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q cipher | cipher-auth | mac | kex | key]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
amit@sharknado:~$
```

Comment: `read -p` is a bashism; it will almost certainly not work if `/bin/sh` is not a link to `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that instead of double quotes, i just needed to use single quotes for the `-c` argument

```
amit@sharknado:~$ /bin/sh -c 'read -p "username: " username; ssh -l $username localhost'
username: testfoo
testfoo@localhost's password:
```

Comment: This is because `$variable` references are expanded in double-quotes, so the `$username` was getting replaced by a blank *before* being passed to `/bin/sh -c`. With single-quotes, it's not expanded by the parent shell, so the `/bin/sh -c` subshell can see and expand it. BTW, you could also get the same effect by escaping the `$` (as in `/bin/sh -c "read ... ssh -l \$username localhost"`)

Comment: @GordonDavisson, I upvote this comment, but I disagree with your definition of "subshell". I consider `sh -c '...'` to start a new shell, not a subshell. In my book, a subshell is a fork of a shell that inherits the shell options, variables, aliases, functions, etc... of the parent (no execve(2) involved).

Comment: @geirha Upon due consideration... I agree with you. It's a shell running as a subprocess, but not technically a "subshell".